# module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_edgelist'

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, data-analysis

here is my code:

```
employee_movie_choices = pd.read_csv('Employee_Movie_Choices.txt', sep="\t")
B = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(employee_movie_choices, '#Employee', 'Movie')
```

and there is an error:**AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_edgelist'***
however, this the documents of networx we could find networkx has the attribute.
here is the link of the documents:[from_pandas_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html?highlight=pandas#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist)

why did this question happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you defining the alias nx as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
```

If yes, try calling the required function as follows:

```
import networkx as nx 
......
......
nx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist(...)
```

Comment: you are right. I asked a stupid question! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I believe, no question is stupid until you know the answer :).

Comment: Your code will end up being very confusing for others since `import networkx as nx` is idiomatic. What you should probably do is `import networkx as nx` and then call `nx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist(...)`

Comment: agreed. Fixed. Thanks @Randy

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use anothor function `from_pandas_dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
edges = pd.DataFrame()
# start
edges['sources'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
# end
edges['targets'] = [2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4]
# weight
edges['weights'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

# build the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(
    edges,
    source='sources',
    target='targets',
    edge_attr='weights')
```